# Tensor product of the state of a system after partial measurement

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve the question below:

[image]

While solving the post measurement state, I understand we can take the 1st and last qubit common using tensor product if they are the same(1st part of the handwritten notes)

Is this true/correct to write for the qubits in the middle as well? That is, is the the correct representation of the system using tensor product (2nd part of the handwritten notes)?

My solution:

$$\lvert\psi\rangle = \frac{\sqrt 2 + i}{\sqrt{20}}\lvert 000\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\lvert 001\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 10}\lvert 011\rangle + \frac{i}{2}\lvert 111\rangle$$

1. After measuring 1st qubit as $\lvert 0\rangle$, the state of the system is:
   $$\begin{align}
   \frac{\tfrac{\sqrt 2 + i}{\sqrt{20}}\lvert 000\rangle
       + \tfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\lvert 001\rangle + \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\lvert 011\rangle}{\sqrt{|\tfrac{\sqrt 2 + i}{\sqrt{20}}|^2 +
       |\tfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}|^2 + |\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}|^2}} 
       &=
       \tfrac{\sqrt{2}+i}{\sqrt{15}}\lvert 000\rangle +
       \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}\lvert 001\rangle +\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{15}}\lvert
       011\rangle \\ 
       &= \lvert 0\rangle \otimes \bigg(\tfrac{\sqrt{2}+i}{\sqrt{15}}\lvert 00\rangle +
       \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}\lvert 01\rangle +\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{15}}\lvert
       11\rangle\bigg)\end{align}$$
2. After measuring the second qubit as $\lvert 1\rangle$, the state of the system is:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\lvert 011\rangle + \tfrac{i}{2}\lvert 111\rangle}{\sqrt{|\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}|^2 + |\tfrac{i}{2}|^2}}
&= \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\lvert 011\rangle + \tfrac{i\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{3}}\lvert 111\rangle \\
&=^? \bigg(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\lvert 0\rangle + \tfrac{i\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{3}}\lvert 1\rangle\bigg)\otimes \lvert 1\rangle \otimes \bigg(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt 6}\lvert 1\rangle + \tfrac{i\sqrt{5}}{3}\lvert 1\rangle\bigg)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please use MathJax instead of posting pictures of large blocks of text...

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I am little new here, will keep this in mind. Thanks!

Comment: @Saniaaa You should try to edit your post so it does not include images.